# How to display/monitor the tail of a growing CSV file in tabular format?

Tags: csv, tail, viewer

I am looking for a way to display an open, "live" CSV file under Windows 7. For example, I have a proprietary program running that is generating log data in CSV format. I'd like to keep an eye on what it's recording, while it's running (read-only - no need/desire to edit or change the file).

Ideally, I want to:

1. display the data in tabular format in a window (like in Excel - but I don't want to use Excel -- this is not the same as [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/533018/open-a-csv-file-in-excel-and-have-it-update-whenever-csv-file-changes/561313#561313))
2. recognize the first line with the column titles to be used as a static title line.
3. vertically scroll around the file, if needed.
4. auto-update, i.e., detect new lines and show the new line(s) at the bottom of the window.
5. auto-scroll to show a new line if I'm positioned at the bottom
6. handle a wide tables (horizontal scrolling).
7. select which columns to show (nice, but not required)

To solve this problem, I've looked at a number of CSV file editor & viewing programs, including [Ron's Editor](http://www.ronsplace.eu/RonsPlace/Products/RonsEditor.aspx), [CSVed](http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/), and nirsoft's [CSV File Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/csv_file_view.html).

The first two are too heavy and have functionality and clutter I'm not interested in (e.g., editing) - and they are missing the auto-update feature. Nirsoft's tool is nearly perfect. But it has only "auto-refresh" which reads the whole file over again & repositions to the top - when I want to stay where I was or have it auto-scroll if I'm at the bottom.

I also took a look at baretail, but it seems to not be designed to handle CSV files.

Regarding file size - it's nice if the solution can handle huge files, but I'll also be happy if it can handle just a few megabytes.

Any suggestions for a way to do what I need?

Comment: Dear SU friends. I am not sure why this is off-topic - it seems rather similar to other questions (though with a specific need). In any case, can you recommend a place to re-ask or migrate it to, please? Thanks.

Comment: It's off topic because it's looking **solely** to recommend software and not for a solution to a problem.  All sites within Stack Exchange are the same way, in that they discourage questions that simply ask for "recommend product that does X".  Feel free to use [this meta post](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5373/47225) for help in re-phrasing the question.

Comment: Hi @yosh-m, I can appreciate that it can be confusing as to why something has been closed. Unfortunately, the close voting process doesn't really encourage voters to give a clear reason. In this case, your question has been closed because it meets the off-topic requirements defined in the FAQ. Namely not "asking for a shopping or product recommendation". These have been set by the originators of the group so we have little influence there. I suggest trying to ask this in [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Thanks, KronoS and JulianKnight, I've followed your advice and re-phrased the question - I hope it will be re-opened. If not, I guess I'll try StackOverflow as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Question: Having re-phrased my question to, I hope, meet the requirements - should I wait/beg for it to be re-opened or is the correct procedure to re-post in its re-phrased form?

Comment: Do not re-post it (yet). If it doesn't get opened here, then you can ask a moderator (by flagging it) to move it to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I checked in on the tool by Nirsoft,  [CSV File Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/csv_file_view.html). The newest version of the tool, 1.75, has added most of the features I was seeking:

> Version 1.75:
>
> - Added 'Partial Refresh' option (Ctrl+F5), which makes a
>   smooth refresh, without reloading the entire table. However, Partial
>   Refresh will not work properly if you add/remove columns or change
>   their position.
> - Added 'Auto Refresh Mode' which allows you to choose
>   how to refresh when the 'Auto Refresh' option is turned on - Partial
>   Refresh or Full refresh.

I tried the new version & it does work as advertised. I wish it automatically kept the end of file in view, but it does not - pressing the <kbd>End</kbd> key brings it quickly back into view. Maybe I'll write an [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) macro to automatically press <kbd>End</kbd> every few seconds for me to get the rest of the functionality I want.

I also tried removing viewed columns while it was auto-partial-refreshing - despite the warning noted above, it continued to work fine.

EDIT: 2013-05-21
Checked back again today and I see Nirsoft has added the "auto-scroll to end on update" function that I was looking for  - it was added in version 1.76 - current version of 1.80.