# Update data automatic

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a sheet which contains column for transactions date, transaction Ids, and transaction status.

I want to update status of the transaction Id daily automatic according to the date I will give to source file

Date refers to date of transaction and ID refers to transaction number and Status refers to if transaction has been delivered to customer or not yet

What I am looking for is, whenever there is an update in the status field, to be updated automatically to avoid any duplication

```
| Transaction Date | Transaction ID | Transaction Status | Employee | Transaction Value |
|------------------|----------------|--------------------|----------|-------------------|
| 09/01/2016       | 234            | Approved           | John     | 10                |
| 09/01/2016       | 235            | Pending            | John     | 10                |
| 09/03/2016       | 238            | Approved           | Mike     | 10                |
| 09/04/2016       | 240            | Pending            | John     | 10                |
| 09/07/2016       | 235            | Approved           | John     | 10                |
| 09/07/2016       | 240            | Rejected           | John     | 10                |
```

Comment: Please add some sample data with desired results to help us understanding your issue. (take a screenshot, upload it to e.g. [imgur](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), then post the link in your question; or you can format your data as a table [here](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)).

Comment: Is that clear ?

Comment: Done, please advice

Comment: You state "*whenever there is an update in the status field, to be updated automatically to avoid any duplication*". This is still unclear.  What does that mean?

Comment: it's still not clear how you want to update the data. Also please delete your comments which are already included in the question, they just disturb reading now.

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688982/derived-account-balance-vs-stored-account-balance-for-a-simple-bank-account/29713230#29713230): It says: "**Don't duplicate data.**"

In Microsoft Excel and in OpenOffice Calc you can link data:

- Calc: Use this construct: `='file:///home/theuser/source.ods'#$Table1.A1`
- In Excel there are more steps necessary, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/533018/open-a-csv-file-in-excel-and-have-it-update-whenever-csv-file-changes).
  UPDATE: the simple way is `=[source.xlsx]Table1!B2` or `=SUM('D:\Documents\[source.xlsx]Table1!'B2)` for closed documents, see comments [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/12/08/excel-reference-another-sheet-workbook/).

Comment: And according to the linked answer you will have to "close the books" after certain time intervals.

Comment: Your links may theoretically answer the question, but because links die [it would be preferable](//meta.superuser.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: OK, main answer was "Don't duplicate data", but the question has been edited so that the answer is now part of the question. The links were meant to provide a hint. Now I have extended the hint.

Comment: That is better. Just keep in mind that we are not here to give hints in the answer area. Hints can be given in the comments. Answers should always be complete and detailed.